# "Blurted" vs "blurted out"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Are the two the same thing? Example:

> “Exploding Whale?” I blurted. “You mean someone blew up a whale with
>   dynamite?”
>
> “Exploding Whale?” I blurted out. “You mean someone blew up a whale with
>   dynamite?”

What would be the difference in this case? Maybe none? I checked in the [dictionary](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=blurted%20defien&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=I6PmVdvhBsLt0gSD97vgBA) and there's *blurted* but not *blurted out*, however the dictionary example of blurted has and *out*: "she blurted out the truth".

When I typed blurted out on Google I got this:

> to utter suddenly or inadvertently; divulge impulsively or unadvisedly
>   (usually followed by out): He blurted out the hiding place of the spy.

It says usually followed by **out**. But it doesn't say why or when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an advervial use of *out* that  adds emphasis to some actions:

[Out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/out):

> - without inhibition; boldly: *speak out*.
> - aloud or loudly: cry *out*

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

The *OED* uses the words "abruptly," "eruptively," "impulsively," and "burst out" to define "blurt" for verbal expression.  So the word by itself contains enough of a propulsive sense so that "out" is redundant.  However, the word "out" is appended often enough the combination is almost a set phrase.  The google, for instance, finds 775K uses of "blurt" and 773K of "blurt out."  Even allowing for some inevitable false drops, that's a close association.

Comment: So it seems one could safely use _blurted out_ in any instance.  It is a strong _collocation_, maybe even a _set phrase_. But not an idiom, as it literally means blurt+out.  Right?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Yes, yes, and yes.  I used idiomatic in a informal sense that's perhaps unwise on this forum.  It's better to reserve the word, as you point out, for situations where the whole is not deducible from its parts.  Which doesn't apply here.  Thanks for the gentle correction.