# Quotative for 'to voice concern'?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a quotative verb (or one I can abuse as a quotative) that means "to voice [a] concern"? (Other than "worried"?)

> "Hey, uh... guys," I _____ed, "it looks like it's getting bigger..."

There are a bunch of verbs for *complaining* (grouse, gripe, whine), there's "warn" if I want to be more definite, but is there a word for 'concerned, but uncertain'? ("Flagged" would sort-of worked except that'd be a real stretch as a quotative. "Advised" is also 'close, but not quite'.)

Comment: *Noted,* maybe?

Comment: "Pointed out." or "warned" could work

Answer (score 1):

> "Hey, uh... guys," I ***exclaimed***, "it looks like it's getting
>   bigger..."

Exclaimed means: cry out suddenly in surprise, strong emotion, or pain.

Comment: Yeah... I'm looking for more tentative, less excitable, but points anyway because I didn't specify that.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't find the quotative usage in a dictionary, [WordNet](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/gulped) comes close:

> - He gulped for help after choking on a big piece of meat

I'm quite familiar with **gulp** being used in this way.

> "Hey, uh ... guys," I gulped, "it looks like it's getting bigger ...."

Killerk, on [HiNative](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/2112327) addresses the semantics:

> To gulp means to "swallow", but this is done when a person is nervous,
> stressed, or scared.

Examples of the quotative usage on the internet include:

> - “I’ve always admired Churchill,” he gulped as he ended his tour of a new exhibition, Churchill and the Great Republic, in the Library of
>   Congress.

[[Elaine Monaghan, The Times, 2004](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/churchill-archive-displays-us-links-lz0dtfjbf2n)]

> - "For God's sake I'm in agony," he gulped.

[[Karen Bate; Salisbury Journal; 2015](https://www.salisburyjournal.co.uk/news/12885705.bate-in-the-wood/)]

Answer (score 0):

You said "concerned, but uncertain" and commented "I'm looking for more tentative, less excitable, but points anyway"

> "Hey, uh... guys," I **mused**, "it looks like it's getting bigger..."

**muse** (v.)

> To think or say (something) in a thoughtful way [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mused)

---

> Merhi smoked his Cedar King Size openly. "Another warning," he **mused**.
> [David Cullen; *The Lebanese Collection*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Lebanese_Collection/YqzJCQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Maybe%20it%27s%20a%20warning%20he%20mused&pg=PA177&printsec=frontcover) (2010)

> "Hullo, they must certainly be getting close now,” he **mused**. “I
> wonder if it is safe for me to try to go on?" [Edward Stratemeyer;
> *Under MacAthur in Luzon*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Under_MacArthur_in_Luzon/7rB9kdVzMwEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Hullo,%20they%20must%20certainly%20be%20getting%20close%20now,%E2%80%9D%20he%20mused.%20%E2%80%9CI%20wonder%20if%20it%20is%20safe%20for%20me%20to%20try%20to%20go%20on%3F&pg=PA50&printsec=frontcover) (1901)

> "Strange," Sherlock **mused**. "We are in Shinagawa Daiba, a section of
> Tokyo. Why should Chairman Ito be barred entry?..." [Keisuke Matsuoka;
> *Sherlock Holmes: A Scandal in Japan*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sherlock_Holmes_A_Scandal_in_Japan/ozGLDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Sherlock%20mused&pg=PT156&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

Answer (score 0):

quotative? I'm flummoxed by the question...

"Hey, uh... guys," I **blurted out**, "it looks like it's getting bigger..."

blurt out: a strong action verb

[enter link description here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/blurt--out#:%7E:text=Say%20abruptly%20or%20inadvertently%2C%20utter,Late%201500s%5D)

You blurt something out before you have time to think but it is generally in reaction to some concern that is triggered in your mind.

Comment: Also "Hey, uh... guys," I blurted, "it looks like it's getting bigger..."  I like *blurted*.

Comment: @aparente001 I don't think I've ever seen it as a non-phrasal. :)

Comment: I haven't read this carefully yet (I'm talking to health insurance): https://english.stackexchange.com/q/270694/112436

Comment: I just know someone who's always about to come over and fix things.